# How disrupting are interrupts to the context? How does one restore it?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

[§5.1.2.3.5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> 5 When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by
> receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free
> atomic objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are  not specified,
> as is the state of the floating-point environment. The value of any
> object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic
> object nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t **becomes indeterminate when
> the handler exits, as does the state of the floating-point environment
> if it is modified by the handler and not restored to its original
> state.**

(emphasis mine)

I take this to mean that, in case of a hardware/software interrupt, if the interrupt handler performs any floating point computations (e.g. on it's local stack variable), the interrupted process is left in an inconsistent state and must restart any floating point computations that were in progress. *Is that it and what are the implications? How does one "restore the context"?*

Comment: will u elaborate ur question more!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "floating-point environment" refers to the set up of floating point exceptions and rounding modes, as modified by functions like `fesetround()`.

You can save the current floating point environment with `fegetenv()`, and restore it with `fesetenv()`.  If you install a signal handler that performs floating point operations, then it should do this (this ensures that it doesn't, for example, alter the set of currently raised floating point exceptions for the code it interrupted).

Answer (score 0):

I think we can perform floating point operations in side kernel. but kernel supports it via calling some specific functions if this(your code) is surrounded by **kernel_fpu_begin()/kernel_fpu_end()**. These function handle saving and restoring the fpu context. Also, they call **preempt_disable()/preempt_enable()**, which means no sleeping, page faults etc.

when ever any interrupt occurs then the current running process's control registers & other information is saved. & the kernel interrupt works it doesn't matter in which state the current running process was because **the process will be interrupted only after completing the current instruction cycle. then save all info & context switching occurs**.

during restore the context the stored control info of the interrupted process is restored in the stack & the next instructions are executed!!!